# installing internet facing snaps as root vs regular user (with sudo priviledges)

Tags: security, snap, lxd

I plan to run a **WeKan** instance inside an **LXD container** on a vps which shall be **accessible via internet**.

Is there any difference from a security point of view whether I do ...

1. `snap install wekan` (as root) vs
2. `sudo snap install wekan` (as a user in the sudo group)

any comments and explanations will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no effective difference: The final result (installing the snap) will be the same.

Ubuntu systems running on bare metal have the root prompt disabled for some very good reasons.

Unprivileged LXD containers, however, are a bit different:

- Unprivileged LXD containers have an enabled root prompt...but it's not the host root.
- Creating a sudo-enabled admin account is optional, since there is an enabled root account.
- You can also control the container from the host: `lxc exec container-name -- snap install wekan`. Note the lack of sudo for an unprivileged container.

Use whichever method you are more comfortable using, and is permitted by your organization policies.

**Testimonial**: My own LXC containers have no human admin accounts. I use the `lxc exec` method most often.

Answer (score 0):

There is no real difference between running `snap install mypackage` as root, and running `sudo snap install mypackage`.

In fact, if, as a non-root user, you run the following and log in into snap (create account at https://login.ubuntu.com/ if you do not have one already)

```
sudo snap login
```

then you can run the following as a non-root (but logged in into *Snap*):

```
snap install mypackage
```

When you run a snap package, you are running the software on top of a Linux runtime that has several built-in restrictions for things that this application should not access. Sort of like a firewall.

When you run a LXD container, you are running the whole Linux runtime in a way that it behaves like a Linux distribution, with several build-in restrictions that separate it from the host.

Running a snap package inside a LXD container is adding similar types of restrictions on top of each other. It might appear overkill, but it is fine.

Comment: I was never aware on logging in to snap as you suggest. Neither would I want that. That said I am not a regular snap user just in this case it seemed pretty handy to get going very quickly,